# How to get rows with specific condition?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set as I've shown below:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~cat_id,   ~clicks,     ~price,
  "1",         NA,           1.2,
  "1",         T,           1.4,         
  "1",         F,           2.2,
  "2",         F,           2.2, 
  "2",         T,           1.5,
  "2",        NA,           1.6,
  "3",         T,           1.7,
  "3",         F,           1.9,
  "4",         F,           1.4,
)
```

But now, I want to get the rows if "click" has ONLY "F" value. My desired data is like this:

```
desired_data <- tribble(
  ~cat_id,   ~clicks,     ~price,
  "4",         F,           1.4,
)
```

To get it, I coded like this but it did not work well:

```
data %>% 
  filter(clicks == "F" & clicks != "T" & clicks != "NA")
```

Do you have any idea what I am making wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be great if you can at least let me know why you vote the question negative since I have no idea...

Comment: are you saying you don't want row 3 for example because rows 1 and 2 have clicks = F and clicks = na? you're not clear on this. you're option here would be to change your filter to `all(clicks == F)` and then use a group_by id

Comment: @zineda, I edited my answer for getting your expected output

Comment: Logical values are their own data type, not just strings. `T` (or better yet, `TRUE`) != `"T"`. Same goes for `NA`—it has an actual meaning, it's not just the letters `"NA"`. I'm guessing downvotes are for not doing basic research, including just looking at the types of values that are in your data frame

Comment: It's also unclear what you're trying to do. `filter` happens by row, so in addition to the typo I mentioned already, if you're trying to do something by group ID, you haven't written code that would deal with groups and haven't described it. "It didn't work well" isn't a clear explanation of what you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,  you can  count for the number of levels of each `cat_id` using tally and then filter rows that are both `clicks -- F` and `n == 1`.

```r
data %>% group_by(cat_id) %>% add_tally() %>% filter(., clicks == F & n ==1)

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   cat_id [1]
  cat_id clicks price     n
  <chr>  <lgl>  <dbl> <int>
1 4      FALSE    1.4     1
```

Comment: But then I might get the cat_id's if there are TRUE or NA values as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it ? What are you looking for ? in your question, you want to get rows with clicks == F, right ?

Comment: I've already mentioned my desired dataset. It is not only clicks == F, others should be there if they have another values such as TRUE or NA in clicks.

Answer (score 2):

@dc37 was ahead of me with edit

Your answer was downvoted because people didn't understand your wording. I'm guessing you meant that some rows were not valid because they have a T or NA for the same ID.

```
data  %>% group_by(., cat_id)%>% filter(., all(clicks == F))
```

Answer (score 2):

is it this what you're looking for?

```
data %>%
  group_by(cat_id) %>%
  filter(!any(clicks)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

edit: if clicks is a factor

```
data <- tribble(
  ~cat_id,   ~clicks,     ~price,
  "1",         NA,           1.2,
  "1",         T,           1.4,         
  "1",         F,           2.2,
  "2",         F,           2.2, 
  "2",         T,           1.5,
  "2",        NA,           1.6,
  "3",         T,           1.7,
  "3",         F,           1.9,
  "4",         F,           1.4,
)

data$clicks <- factor(data$clicks, labels = c("F", "T"))

data %>%
  group_by(cat_id) %>%
  filter(all(clicks == "F")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi, I got this error: ‘any’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: in your example data clicks is a logical column. You get that error because in your actual data clicks is a factor. Look at my edit